# Strange equation of the second degree

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $ a $ and $ b $ be positive non-null real numbers for which $ 9a-3b = 5 $ is equal. Therefore, determine the numeric value of the expression $ \frac {b} {2a} + \frac {\sqrt {b ^ 2 + 20a}} {2a}$

The tip of the question is $ 9 = 3 ^ 2 $.

What I tried $ Ax ^ 2 + Bx + C = 0 $

$$ x = \frac {-B + \sqrt {B ^ 2-4AC}} {2A} $$

And replaces the iconites

Forcing equality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quadratic formula is indeed the way to go. We want to find the larger root of $$ax^2-bx-5=0$$

Note that from the hint,  we might guess that $3$ is a root, which it is by the given equation.  Note that the vertex of the quadratic is at $\frac b{2a}=1.5-\frac5{6a}<3$. This implies that $3$ is the larger root and hence the solution.

Another way to see $3$ is the larger root is by Vieta's formulas.  We know that the product of the roots is $-\frac5a<0$. So, since $3$ is positive,  the other root is negative.

P.S. Note that this proof doesn't rely on $b>0$.

Answer (score 0):

There's another solution.  Substituting $b=(9a-5)/3$ in
$$ \dfrac {b} {2a} + \dfrac {\sqrt {b ^ 2 + 20a}} {2a}$$
we'll get
$$\frac{-5+9a+\sqrt{(5+9a)^2}}{6a}.$$
Now if $a\geq-5/9$ this will be $3$, otherwise it will be $-\frac{5}{3a}$.

Answer (score 0):

The given expression is the largest root of

$$ax^2+bx-5=0$$

and we are told that

$$a\,3^2-b\,3-5=0.$$
By subtraction,

$$a(x+3)(x-3)+b(x-3)=0$$ so that the other root is

$$x=-\frac ba-3,$$ which is smaller.

---

By direct computation,

$$a=\frac{3b+5}9,$$

$$\sqrt{b^2+20a}=\frac{3b+10}3,$$

$$b+\sqrt{b^2+20a}=2\frac{3b+5}3,$$

$$\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2+20a}}{2a}=3.$$